# Installed ubuntu 20.04 from 0 - x509: certificate signed by unknown authority error on every app

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, snap, certificates, pycharm

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04. Considering the time that passed since its release I thought it would be stable. After installing it, I go to Snap Store (named Ubuntu Software) and I see that several new programs appear, but after a few moments, only the editor picks show, nothing else.

I try to install PyCharm through the command line with snap, `sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic` but it gives me this error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.

Afterwards, I decide to purge snap store and reinstall it, and after running these 2 commands: `sudo apt-get update`,`sudo apt install snapd`, I enter this one `sudo snap install snap-store` and gives me again, the same error with the certificates.

I got no idea whats going on. I installed it from 0

*Edit 1*:
Output of `snap list`:

```
No snaps are installed yet. Try 'snap install hello-world'.
```

Output of `sudo snap install snap-store`:

```
error: cannot install "snap-store": Post
       https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: x509: certificate signed by
       unknown authority
```

Comment: Hey learn123456! What's the output of `apt-cache policy snapd`?

Comment: @technastic_tc `.snapd:
  Installed: 2.46.1+20.04
  Candidate: 2.46.1+20.04
  Version table:
 *** 2.46.1+20.04 500`.

Answer (score 2):

This may be due to a missing trusted CA certificate.

### Verification of the cause

#### Test #1

```
openssl s_client -connect api.snapcraft.io:443
```

Example of a response that confirms a missing CA certificate. See line with `verify error`:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect api.snapcraft.io:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

#### Test #2

```
ls -l /etc/ssl/certs | grep -i digicert
```

DigiCert CA certificates should be displayed e.g. as follows

```
b1159c4c.0 -> DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_CA.pem
dd8e9d41.0 -> DigiCert_Global_Root_G3.pem
244b5494.0 -> DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.pem
3513523f.0 -> DigiCert_Global_Root_CA.pem
607986c7.0 -> DigiCert_Global_Root_G2.pem
7f3d5d1d.0 -> DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G3.pem
75d1b2ed.0 -> DigiCert_Trusted_Root_G4.pem
9d04f354.0 -> DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_G2.pem
```

When they are not, they need to be added.

### Solution

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
sudo systemctl restart snapd
sudo snap refresh
```

The first command allows you to add interactively new CA certificates. The source for adding certificates can usually be found in the directory
`/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/`

If certificates are missing there, they can be downloaded from
https://www.digicert.com/kb/digicert-root-certificates.htm

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue within corporate network where there is installed zscaler firewall which does SSL inspection by injecting its own ROOT CA, in my case I extracted this custom root CA(you can use openssl or browser) in pem format:

```
zangetsu@CZ-6FXPQV3:~/zscaler-intermediate-chain$ cat /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/zscaler_root_ca.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE0zCCA7ugAwIBAgIJANu+mC2Jt3uTMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGhMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTERMA8GA1UEBxMIU2FuIEpvc2Ux
FTATBgNVBAoTDFpzY2FsZXIgSW5jLjEVMBMGA1UECxMMWnNjYWxlciBJbmMuMRgw
FgYDVQQDEw9ac2NhbGVyIFJvb3QgQ0ExIjAgBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWE3N1cHBvcnRA
enNjYWxlci5jb20wHhcNMTQxMjE5MDAyNzU1WhcNNDIwNTA2MDAyNzU1WjCBoTEL
MAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExETAPBgNVBAcTCFNhbiBK
b3NlMRUwEwYDVQQKEwxac2NhbGVyIEluYy4xFTATBgNVBAsTDFpzY2FsZXIgSW5j
LjEYMBYGA1UEAxMPWnNjYWxlciBSb290IENBMSIwIAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhNzdXBw
b3J0QHpzY2FsZXIuY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA
qT7STSxZRTgEFFf6doHajSc1vk5jmzmM6BWuOo044EsaTc9eVEV/HjH/1DWzZtcr
fTj+ni205apMTlKBW3UYR+lyLHQ9FoZiDXYXK8poKSV5+Tm0Vls/5Kb8mkhVVqv7
LgYEmvEY7HPY+i1nEGZCa46ZXCOohJ0mBEtB9JVlpDIO+nN0hUMAYYdZ1KZWCMNf
5J/aTZiShsorN2A38iSOhdd+mcRM4iNL3gsLu99XhKnRqKoHeH83lVdfu1XBeoQz
z5V6gA3kbRvhDwoIlTBeMa5l4yRdJAfdpkbFzqiwSgNdhbxTHnYYorDzKfr2rEFM
dsMU0DHdeAZf711+1CunuQIDAQABo4IBCjCCAQYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFLm33UrNww4M
hp1d3+wcBGnFTpjfMIHWBgNVHSMEgc4wgcuAFLm33UrNww4Mhp1d3+wcBGnFTpjf
oYGnpIGkMIGhMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTERMA8G
A1UEBxMIU2FuIEpvc2UxFTATBgNVBAoTDFpzY2FsZXIgSW5jLjEVMBMGA1UECxMM
WnNjYWxlciBJbmMuMRgwFgYDVQQDEw9ac2NhbGVyIFJvb3QgQ0ExIjAgBgkqhkiG
9w0BCQEWE3N1cHBvcnRAenNjYWxlci5jb22CCQDbvpgtibd7kzAMBgNVHRMEBTAD
AQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQAw0NdJh8w3NsJu4KHuVZUrmZgIohnTm0j+
RTmYQ9IKA/pvxAcA6K1i/LO+Bt+tCX+C0yxqB8qzuo+4vAzoY5JEBhyhBhf1uK+P
/WVWFZN/+hTgpSbZgzUEnWQG2gOVd24msex+0Sr7hyr9vn6OueH+jj+vCMiAm5+u
kd7lLvJsBu3AO3jGWVLyPkS3i6Gf+rwAp1OsRrv3WnbkYcFf9xjuaf4z0hRCrLN2
xFNjavxrHmsH8jPHVvgc1VD0Opja0l/BRVauTrUaoW6tE+wFG5rEcPGS80jjHK4S
pB5iDj2mUZH1T8lzYtuZy0ZPirxmtsk3135+CKNa2OCAhhFjE0xd
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Now I had to put the file into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` folder and run `sudo update-ca-certificates`

Now the another problem is with snap, that its using mount/copy of the local store where this certificate is not, so I had to run:

```
sudo mount --bind --bind -o nodev,ro /etc/ssl/certs /snap/core22/current/etc/ssl/certs/
```

As a stop gap until snap finds a way to manage root CA for all applications you can create a systemd mount file to run on startup:

```
$ cat <<-EOF | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/snap-core-current-etc-ssl-certs.mount
[Unit]
Description=Mount unit to fix etc ssl certs in core package
After=snapd.service

[Mount]
What=/etc/ssl/certs
Where=/snap/core/current/etc/ssl/certs
Type=none
Options=bind,nodev,ro

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
$ systemctl enable snap-core-current-etc-ssl-certs.mount
```